# Get class name from the class who extend it

Tags: c#

I have a class like this

```
public class BaseClass
    {
        public string Request { get; set;}
    }
```

and I have the class like this :

```
public class ExtendClass : BaseClass
{

}
```

So actually the property Request will always be set with the name of ExtendClass. So it actually will be `Request="ExtendClass"`

I have many class who extend BaseClass. I know I just can pass string to it, but is that possible to do it?

Comment: Elaborate more on question. Do you want each time extended class is created it should set Request="ExtendClass" ?

Comment: Completely unclear what you are looking for, you want to set the Request property when any of the child class inheriting the BaseClass is called, something like when ExtendedClass is called, then you should be able to set the Request property. You can in view use constructor to do it

Comment: @blueboyz Does [Object.GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) method not work for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`object.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will always return the type on top in the hierarchy (so the last deriving class):

```
public string Request
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

[`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.name(v=vs.110).aspx) will return the short type name, without the namespace. If you want that too, you should use [`FullName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple choices. For example, you can use reflections:

```
public string Request { get {return this.GetType().Name; }}
```

Or you can make it more explicit, with abstract property (and that way you can specify not only class names):

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract string Request { get; }
}
class ExtendClass : BaseClass
{
    public override string Request { get {return "ExtendClass"; } }
}
```